# jQuery Mobile: How to change only one listview item dynamicly, inside collapsible-set

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a Collapsible-set with listview. If I tap on one item a panel opens and displays all info about it.

```
$("#mySet").on("tap", "li", function(e)
```

I can get the info from the selected item, but on the panel there is also a button. If I tap this button I want my item in the listview to change color or add icon. The LI-item doesn't have an ID, but I know which index it has and which value and so on.

Pseudo code for updating listview item:

```
SELECT WHERE header="category 1" // currently opened
CHANGE item WHERE [data-item] = "10601"
```

Any ideas? This is content of a collapsible (collapsible-set holds 10+ of these)

```
<div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-a" aria-hidden="false">
<p></p>
<ul class="ui-listview" data-role="listview">
<li class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-first-child" data-description="xxx" data-item="10101">
<li class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-first-child" data-description="yyy" data-item="50101">
<li class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-first-child" data-description="zzz" data-item="10601">
<li class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-first-child" data-description="qqq" data-item="13105">
</ul>
<p></p>
</div>
```

This "works", but will update ALL items where data-item=10601

```
 $("#mySet [data-item='10601']").text("Updated");
```

How do I only select this item but ONLY current opened collapsible?

**UPDATE:**

I solved it...

```
$("#mySet li[data-item='"+ item + "'][data-description='"+ desc + "']" ).text("foo!");
```

Comment: can you please give more information about the structure of your elements?

Comment: One collapsible set: 10 Headers, and under each header (UL), i have 10 items (LI)

Comment: li is containing 10 headers and each header is containing 10 items of which element? It's easier if you post your html code...

Comment: updated my question, more examples